# What to do with a 1 --> 0..1 relationship?

Tags: database, foreign-keys, entity-relationship, cardinality

We have a `Claim` entity which might be proved by either a `EmailVerification` , put `MetaCode` in the relevant website or uploading `CertificateFile`. Now the problem is the claimer may choose to prove their claim by using any combination of the methods menetioned but in each category they got only one shot. Meaning :

```
 Claim -- 0..1 --> EmialVerification
 Claim -- 0..1 --> MetaCode
 Claim -- 0..1 --> CertificateFile
```

so this is valid:

```
 Claim #20 --> EmialVerification #12
 Claim #20 --> MetaCode (none)
 Claim #20 --> CertificateFile #124
```

also this:

```
 Claim #34 --> EmialVerification (none)
 Claim #34 --> MetaCode (none)
 Claim #34 --> CertificateFile (none)
```

but **not** this:

```
 Claim #34 --> EmialVerification #1034 & #450
 Claim #34 --> MetaCode (none)
 Claim #34 --> CertificateFile (none)
```

because #43 is related to two `EmailVerification`s.

Now I'm stuck at the table schema because I don't know how best to model a `0..1` relationship:

- four separate tables with artificial PKs (integer ids) and go as is usual with 1..* relations
- four separate tables but only one has an `id` and the other 3 use this `id` as both their own PK and FK to the `Claim` table ?
- simply aggregate the 3 other tables into the `Claim` table and use `Null` to indication lack of relation ?
- something else ?

EDIT As it appears the question is not very clear : a row in `Claim` can be connected to either 0 (not connected at all) or 1 row in any of the other 3 but any single row in `Claim` can *not* be connected to more than one row in any the other 3 tables (like the 3rd case in the example).

EDIT A terrible typo was lurking in the shadows (`Claim #34` was entered at the first row in each example mistakenly as `Claim #43`) !!! . really sorry. I think the correct answer still holds by the way.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/q/517417/369489

Comment: So the Claim table needs to have a corresponding row in one and only one of the tables EmailVerification, MetaCode, and CertificateFile?

Comment: So must Email, Metacode, and Certificate mutually exclude the others? So if claim #1 is made via email, then neither Metacode nor certificate may hold Claim #1 as a Foreign Key?

Comment: If they mutually exclude, could we create a single 'Proven' table with 1 to 0..1 that holds claim ID as Unique FK and uses an enumerated field to identify the proven method?

Comment: @KacireeSoftware They are not mutually excluded (first case in the example) but if a `Claim` is connected to a `MetaCode` for example, then it can be connected only to one row in `MetaCode` but at the same time can be connected to either one on none row in the other 2 tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After clarifying comments, you seem to need only to store the primary key in the various verification tables.  (You don't have to use an artificial or surrogate key. If "claim_num" is a natural key, and it's varchar(15), use "claim_num".)

```
create table Claims (
  claim_id integer primary key,
  other_columns_go_here char(1) not null default 'x'
);

create table EmailVerifications (
  claim_id integer primary key references Claims (claim_id),
  email_verification_num integer not null unique,
  other_columns_go_here char(1) not null default 'x'
);

create table MetaCodes (
  claim_id integer primary key references Claims (claim_id),
  metacode_num integer not null unique,
  other_columns_go_here char(1) not null default 'x'
);

create table CertificateFiles (
  claim_id integer primary key references Claims (claim_id),
  certificate_file_num integer not null unique,
  other_columns_go_here char(1) not null default 'x'
);
```

These inserts will succeed.

```
insert into Claims values (20);
insert into EmailVerifications values (20, 12);
insert into CertificateFiles values (20, 124);
```

The first two inserts will succeed.  The PRIMARY KEY constraint on "EmailVerifications" will make the third one will fail.

```
insert into Claims values (43);
insert into EmailVerifications values (43, 1034);
insert into EmailVerifications values (43, 450);
```

---

**The following doesn't match the clarified requirements. Consider its continued presence a bonus.**

If I understand correctly, you want each row in Claims to be referenced by either zero rows, or by one and only one row.

```
create table Claims (
  claim_id integer primary key,
  verification_code char(1) not null
    check (verification_code in ('c', 'e', 'm')),
  unique (claim_id, verification_code),
  other_columns_go_here char(1) not null default 'x'
);

create table EmailVerifications (
  claim_id integer not null,
  verification_code char(1) not null default 'e'
    check (verification_code = 'e'),
  primary key (claim_id, verification_code),
  foreign key (claim_id, verification_code)
    references Claims (claim_id, verification_code),
  other_columns_go_here char(1) not null default 'x'
);

create table MetaCodes (
  claim_id integer not null,
  verification_code char(1) not null default 'm'
    check (verification_code = 'm'),
  primary key (claim_id, verification_code),
  foreign key (claim_id, verification_code)
    references Claims (claim_id, verification_code),
  other_columns_go_here char(1) not null default 'x'
);

create table CertificateFiles (
  claim_id integer not null,
  verification_code char(1) not null default 'c'
    check (verification_code = 'c'),
  primary key (claim_id, verification_code),
  foreign key (claim_id, verification_code)
    references Claims (claim_id, verification_code),
  other_columns_go_here char(1) not null default 'x'
);

begin;
  insert into Claims values (1, 'c', 'x');
  insert into CertificateFiles values (1, 'c', 'x');
commit;

begin;
  insert into Claims values (2, 'e', 'x');
  insert into EmailVerifications values (2, 'e', 'x');
commit;

begin;
  insert into Claims values (3, 'm', 'x');
  insert into MetaCodes values (3, 'm', 'x');
commit;
```

The overlapping PRIMARY KEY and UNIQUE constraints in "Claims" are required. Other tables reference the pair of columns "claim_id" and "verification_code", and they can't do that unless there's a UNIQUE constraint on the pair of columns.

The verification_code and its CHECK constraints guarantee that the foreign key reference will come from the right table.

```
-- This insert will fail. 
-- Inserting into EmailVerifications requires 'e', not 'c'.
begin;
  insert into Claims values (4, 'c', 'x');
  insert into EmailVerifications values (4, 'c', 'x');
commit;

-- This insert will fail. (Duplicate row.)
insert into EmailVerifications values (2, 'e', 'x');

-- This insert will fail. (Trying to make two rows reference one row in Claims.)
insert into CertificateFiles values (2, 'e', 'x');
```

Comment: +1 clever use of PK in prove tables to impose the ..1 constraint. Would it be possible to signal the RDBMS (supposing the particular server in question supports this) that the PKs in the prove tables are at the same time actually FKs to `Claim` ?

Comment: @ashy_32bit: Sure. I should have done that to begin with. I'm thinking too hard about job interviews today and tomorrow. Updated code.

Comment: Would you please re-read the question in the light of the second edit :-D ?

Comment: I caught that discrepancy earlier, but used 43 in my testing. My answer (the one at the top) still holds.