# How do I save a child entity in a One-To-One relationship with Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Let's say I have two entities Instructor and InstructorDetail as follows:

Instructor.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "instructor")
public class Instructor {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "instructor_detail_id")
    private InstructorDetail instructorDetail;

        //getters, setters and constructors
```

and InstructorDetail.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "instructor_detail")
public class InstructorDetail {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "youtube_channel")
    private String youtubeChannel;

    @Column(name = "hobby")
    private String hobby;

    @JsonBackReference
        @OneToOne(mappedBy = "instructorDetail", cascade = { 
            CascadeType.DETACH, 
            CascadeType.MERGE, 
            CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.REFRESH })
    private Instructor instructor;

        //getters, setters and constructors
```

The scenario I imagine is where I first save an Instructor and then with a separate POST request I save an InstructorDetail.

So I imagined inserting a field

```
@Column(name = "instructor_id")
private Long instructorId;
```

So this will be my InstructorDetail.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "instructor_detail")
public class InstructorDetail {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    
        @Column(name = "instructor_id")
        private Long instructorId;

    @Column(name = "youtube_channel")
    private String youtubeChannel;

    @Column(name = "hobby")
    private String hobby;

    @JsonBackReference
        @OneToOne(mappedBy = "instructorDetail", cascade = { 
            CascadeType.DETACH, 
            CascadeType.MERGE, 
            CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.REFRESH })
    private Instructor instructor;

        //getters, setters and constructors
```

The DAO implementation

```
@Repository
public class InstructorDetailDAOImpl implements InstructorDetailDAO {
    
    private final EntityManager entityManager;
    
    @Autowired
    public InstructorDetailDAOImpl(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void save(InstructorDetail instructorDetail) {
            Instructor savedInstructor = entityManager.find(Instructor.class,
                instructorDetail.getInstructorId());
        savedInstructor.setInstructorDetail(instructorDetail);
        entityManager.persist(instructorDetail);
    }
```

At this point in a separate POST request with postman i save the instructor:
POST: (it will be saved with id=1)

```
{
    "firstName": "Harry",
    "lastName": "Potter",
    "email": "harry.potter@email.it"
}
```

and with another POST request I save the details parsing the instructorId into the payload

```
{
    "instructorId": 1,
    "youtubeChannel": "www.youtube.it",
    "hobby": "Voldemort"
}
```

Do you think this is the most suitable solution?

Is it better to save the details in a single API along with the instructor? Is the One-To-One relationship configured correctly?
Thank you in advance

Comment: "*Do you think this is the most suitable solution?*" - Without a clear metric for "most suitable", this question is opinion-based and thus off-topic for Stack Overflow. --- "*Is it better to save the details in a single API along with the instructor?*" - Same --- "*Is the One-To-One relationship configured correctly?*" - It looks fine, yes. But why not simply test it? --- Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Comment: Any reason why `InstructorDetail` has its own separate Id field ? As stated previous commentator it-is opinion-based, and on my honest opinion it is redundant here to split this info onto two separate tables/entities

Comment: The reason is that where I work the frontend team always asks for so many different APIs (like in this case), so I wondered if it was really necessary or avoidable

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517417/is-there-ever-a-time-where-using-a-database-11-relationship-makes-sense

Comment: If you want to query or update a part of `Instructor` you can do it straighforward through provided JPA/Spring Data functionality. If you afraid of performance issue on such action - you always can perform native query.