# Confusion about 1:1 relationship

Tags: sql, database-design

I've been learning database design and I'm confused about 1:1 relationships. From what I understand, you can simply add columns to the appropriate table. Can someone provide a real world example of where a 1:1 relationship was either necessary or provided some significant benefit? I.e., where would I use a 1:1 relationship and what would it look like?

Comment: I'd say husband and wife, but it's not always a given.

Comment: A simple case - a single manager manages a single department. However, a manager is also an employee (but not every employee is a manager). It makes sense to abstract out the manager table to help meet all these possible constraints. http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/admin/c0004733.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll give you a real practical example.

In the medical billing world, doctors who want to get paid by medicare handle billing by creating a dictation report for each visit with a patient.  This might actually be a recorded audio dictation transcribed by a secretary, but more often it's just a written description of what they did and talked about with the patient, along with history, impressions, and so forth.  A licensed medical coder will then read this dictation and decide what the doctor is allowed to bill.

Separate from the dictation, there is demographic information about the patient involved: name, age, billing address, etc.  This information *must* be strictly separate from information about the dictation, to prevent coders from allowing bias to cloud their billing judgements or violating patients' privacy.

This data is often kept well-normalized with a 1:many relationship in the data systems at the point of origin, and only the right parts are displayed to the right people at the right times.  However, a significant number of offices out-source their billing function to a third party. This way a small clinic, for example, doesn't have to keep a licensed medical coder on staff; one coder at the billing office can handle the needs of many clinics. When the data is sent from the clinic to the billing office, the patient demographic information and the dictations need to come over as separate pieces, possibly at separate times. At this point, they'll likely be stored in completely separate tables with a 1:1 relationship and a shared ID field to match them up later.

In this case, the 1:1 relationship has very little to do with the data model.  You could probably match up the records at the time of import, and as a bill moves through the system eventually the provincial patient information received in the clinic's demographic record will be matched to a real person so the 1:many relationship can be restored.  Otherwise you'd get a separate statement on a separate account for each visit to the doctor.

Instead, it has almost everything to do with the systems design. There are likely entirely different people building and using the billing part verses the coding part at our imaginary billing service. This way, each side can each have full control of it's own fiefdom, and you are sure that no one, not even a developer, is breaking any privacy rules.

Comment: That's a neat and valid example too. I like it.

Comment: Holy Cow that's complicated. So, in this case, it is to ensure absolute separation of certain parts of the data rather than some requirement in the model of the entities?

Comment: +1 - Excellent answer! I worked on insurance systems for a very small amount of time as an internship in college and, although this case never come up in the work I was doing, this makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the answer, @Joel!

Answer (score 5):

> True one-to-one relationships seldom
> occur in the real world. This type of
> relationship is often created to get
> around some limitation of the database
> management software rather than to
> model a real-world situation. In
> Microsoft Access, one-to-one
> relationships may be necessary in a
> database when you have to split a
> table into two or more tables because
> of security or performance concerns or
> because of the limit of 255 columns
> per table. For example, you might keep
> most patient information in
> tblPatient, but put especially
> sensitive information (e.g., patient
> name, social security number and
> address) in tblConfidential (see
> Figure 3). Access to the information
> in tblConfidential could be more
> restricted than for tblPatient. As a
> second example, perhaps you need to
> transfer only a portion of a large
> table to some other application on a
> regular basis. You can split the table
> into the transferred and the
> non-transferred pieces, and join them
> in a one-to-one relationship.

That's a quote from [here: Fundamentals of Relational Database Design](http://www.deeptraining.com/litwin/dbdesign/FundamentalsOfRelationalDatabaseDesign.aspx)

And here's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517011/design-1-to-1-relationship-db-tables) on SO.

Another reason I can see for using a 1:1 (where I have used it in the past) is if you have a table with a lot of columns, and only a few of them are involved in very intensive and frequent queries which need to be fast, I would break it into two tables that are related 1:1 where I could query the lightweight table and get good performance, but still have the other data related to it easily with a simple join.

Comment: Is it not the case that one can control security and confidentiality through views? In fact, wouldn't that be the preferred approach? The column limitation however sounds like a real limitation that could only be avoided using 1:1.

Comment: I agree with you about the security and confidentiality, and maybe that article doesn't have the best example, but I can definitely see where sometimes you would want some data that is associated to be completely _seperate_ for whatever reason, maybe legal - for instance stock information to prevent insider trading (which I have friends who have actually seen this type of separation for that reason), or medical (see Joel's answer), etc.

Comment: I gave you an upvote (I guess I can do that now) and wish I could claim two answers but I think Joel Coehoorn is a more tangible example I was seeking.

Comment: Actually, 1:1 relationships are not at all uncommon, but most Microsoft Access developers don't seem to know much about supertypes and subtypes. See, for example, the accepted answer to this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969133/database-design-problem

Comment: @catcall: I think the point was that they are an uncommon relationship in the real world relationships, but that they are used (and even sometimes frequently) in data modeling for reasons other than defining a relationship.

Answer (score 2):

I belief tables should be designed with the domain background. So if those columns form two different entities, they should not be mixed in one table. From my experience 1:1 relationships tend to evolve into 1:n relationships over time.

For example you may want to store *the* postal address of a person. But after some time, you are required to store more than one address per person. Refactoring programs from a 1:1 relationship into 1:n is usually a lot easier than extracting some columns from an old table into a new one.

Many database systems allow defining of access permissions per table in a very easy way. But defining permissions on individual columns is often quite painful.

Answer (score 0):

It's useful if X has a 1:1 relationship with Y and Z also has a 1:1 relationship with Y.  Y can be abstracted out into a shared table rather than duplicating in both X and Z.

EDIT: A real world example would be Customers, Companies, and Addresses.  There can be a N:N relationship between Customer and Company.  But both Customer and Company have 1:1 relationships with Address.  Some Address rows could be related to both a Customer and a Person.

Comment: But doesn't this imply that X has a 1:1 with Z, and so they could all live together?

Comment: It makes it possible for X and Z to be related indirectly but that is not a requirement.  See my edit for a more real-world example

Answer (score 0):

First, because they are talking about Access (Jet, Ace, whatever) -- credit to @Richard DesLonde for spotting this -- then they are probably talking about 1:0..1 relationships. I do not believe true 1:1 relationships are workable in Access because it has no mechanism for deferring constraints nor executing multiple statements in a SQL `PROCEDURE`. Most Access practitioners are satisfied to use a 1:0..1 relationship to model a true 1:1 relationship, so I guess the authors are satisfied to use the term "1:1" informally to refer to both.

Of course, 1:1 and 1:1..0 relationships are common enough in the real world. I rather think they are trying to convey the (valid) point that some 1:1 and 1:1..0 relationships are invented in a data model for business purposes.

Consider a "natural person" (i.e. human) and a "corporation". They have no attributes in common (sure, both have a "name" but their domains are different e.g. "natural person name" has sub atomic domains for "family name", "given name" and "title", etc).

However, in a given data model distinct entity types may play the same role. For example, both a "natural person" and a "corporation" can be the officer of a "corporation". In the data model, we could have two distinct entity types "natural person officers" and "corporate officers" that are likely to have many attributes in common and from the same domains e.g. appointment date, termination date, etc; further, they business rules would be the same e.g. appointment date must be before termination date. Also, both would participate in equivalent relationships e.g. "natural person representing", etc.

The data model could be 'split' at high level, resulting in pairs of very similar tables e.g. "natural person officer" and "corporate officer", "natural person officer natural person representing" and "corporate officer natural person representing", etc.

However, another approach is to model the common attributes and relationships using a fabricated entity type. For example, both a "natural person" and a "corporation" could be considered to be a "legal person" (aside: there is such a concept of "legal person" in law but does this mean the same as existing in the real world?!)

Therefore, we could have a superclass table for "legal persons" and subtype tables for "natural persons" and "corporations" respectively. The "officers" table would reference the "legal persons" table. All subsequent relationship tables could reference the "officers" table, which would half the number of tables from this point down.

There are practical problems to such a 'subclassing' approach. Because a "natural person" and a "corporation" has no attributes in common, they have no common key, therefore the "legal persons" table would need to have an artificial key, with all the problems that this entails, especially if it needs to be  exposed in the application. Also, because the relationships between "legal persons", "natural persons" and "corporations" are truly 1:1 some DBMSs, as Access, will lack the necessary functionality to effectively implement them and many will have to settle for making them 1:0..1.

Answer (score -1):

A 1:1 relationship is an abstract concept that you model in your data, but at the database level (assuming RDBMS) doesn't really exist.  You always have a foreign key on one table pointing to another, so technically the parent table being pointed to by the FK could have multiple children.  This is something you'll want to enforce in your business logic.

A good example of a 1:1 relationship in a modeling sense would be the relationship between employee and person.  You have a person with certain data, then you have extra attributes on that same person that you put on an employee.  A good way to think of this in OO programming terms is as inherited classes.  The Employee class, inherits from Person.  In fact may ORM systems will model the 1:1 relationship in the database with each table having a shared primary key.

Comment: Be careful of confusing "1:1" with "1:0 or 1"

Comment: 1:(1or0) is a case of a 1:1 relationship.  It is a constraint on that relationship, but the relationship (if exists) still is 1:1, and still in the db is 1:N because of the FK.

Comment: -1? really.  This is valid.  It is important to know that modeling is different from what you actually have in the db.

Comment: That's ok, I may have just explained it unclearly, or went off topic.  Feel free to vote me down, I may be on my way to a peer pressure badge  :)